# Generate next three month anniversary date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains details on charitable donations and the date they were added to the database.

I am trying to write a query that will display the next date after today that will be a three month anniversary of the record being added to the database.

Given a date in the past, I want my query to return the next date in the future that is a multiple of 3 months from the original date i.e. the three month anniversary.

See below for some examples of expected output given todays date.

```
Date         | Expected output
1st Feb 2015 | 1st May 2015, 
1st Sep 2014 | 1st Jun 2015
```

Comment: `I am trying to write a query` can you put that query here what you tried  ?

Comment: Please add your table structure, example data, expected output and the query you are stuck with.

Comment: @juergen d - Is that necessary? All I want to do is write a query that, given a date in the past, will return the next date from today that is a three month anniversary.

Comment: Means simply you want the date after 3 months from today??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AnkitBajpai not quite - I would like the next date that is a multiple of three months after the date inserted.

Comment: @SimonTindall: You see, with all the data provided you would have a much more precise answer now. Put effort in your question and people will take effort to answer

Comment: What will be the output for '20141129' :)?

Comment: @juergen-d, Apologies, it wasnt through lack of effort on my part, the query is just on dates so I thought table structure and example data were a tad overkill...I realise now that expected output would have been helpful. I'll remember for next time. Thanks

Comment: @SimonTindall, can you answer? What will be the output for '20141129'?
also for '20150331'

Comment: It would just go to the next nearest day, the function written by @daniel-e uses sql dateadd which takes this into account. Thanks

Comment: A ツ had a fair point on the answer, I added a comment there, let me know if you need the answer itself updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that returns your looped date, then call it from your table values. There is probably a fancier/faster way to do  it, but this would get you what you need.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Get3MonthAnniv] (@DateVal DATETIME)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LoopDate DATETIME = @DateVal
    DECLARE @Today as datetime = CONVERT(Date,GETDATE())

    While @loopDate<@today
    BEGIN
        SET @loopDate=DATEADD(Month,3,@loopDate)
    END


    RETURN @loopDate

END
GO

 CREATE TABLE #dates (DateVal DATETIME)

INSERT #dates (DateVal)
VALUES ('1/1/2014')
    ,('1/1/2015')

SELECT DateVal
    ,[dbo].[fn_Get3MonthAnniv](DateVal)
FROM #dates

DROP TABLE #dates
```

Comment: Thats perfect thanks, I modded it slightly to accept another variable for the date interval.

Comment: only it doesnt work if you start with the 2015-11-30 , you'll end up with 2015-05-28

Comment: 11-30-14 you mean I assume.  Thats true, you can change the function to add 90 days, or add a caveat where if the `@loopdate = 2/28/XXXX AND DateVal <> xx/28/XXXX` add 1 day before you continue the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DATEADD function for this task. I use @today variable only for example.

```
DECLARE @threemonth datetime, @today datetime
SET @today = GETUTCDATE()
SELECT @threemonth = DATEADD(month, 3, @today)
```